# Is it possible to export saved passwords from Toad

Tags: export, passwords, toad

I'm looking for a way to export saved usernames/passwords from Toad for Oracle (9.5.0.31).  It doesn't have to be in a usable format for importing - even a plaintext format would be fine.

I believe the passwords are stored encrypted in CONNECTIONPWDS.INI, but from what I've read, that file doesn't transfer from one machine to another.  There doesn't seem to be anything in the Quest site or the Yahoo groups about this, other than "[That's a very good suggestion...](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/toad/message/37320)".

Has anyone had any luck accomplishing this?  Or am I stuck with having to dig up the passwords for each of my accounts?

Thanks

Comment: Have you seen http://damir-vadas.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/retrive-oracle-password-from-toad-for.html Maybe worth try, if anyone has the problem again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this one got me the Tumbleweed badge (no comments or answers for a week)...I guess there's either no Toad experts out there, or no way to do it.

I never could find an answer, so I'm going to assume there's no way to do it, and I'll dig up all of my passwords.

Comment: I found a way to see stored password, see my answer.

Answer (score 16):

I did not find any way to export ALL connections but I can export one by one using the information from following [link](http://damir-vadas.blogspot.com.tr/2013/06/retrive-oracle-password-from-toad-for.html). Trick is to

1. Create db link.
2. Choose one of the existing connections
3. Set user/pass to current
4. Show sql

In the opened window, you can see your stored password. I successfully retrieved my stored password using this way.

Answer (score 3):

i've always used the copy user files from utilities .. copy user files and then I do an export.  when I reinstall on a new machine/laptop after lease rollout, I then import my user settings using the zip file created and everything is populated.  passwords, settings, connection information etc.

Answer (score 2):

In Toad 12.1.X and above , there is option to import and export in the connections screen . If you have already checked "Save Check Box" option . Simply export into a text file and the same text file can be imported to your new toad . It works.

Answer (score 2):

I just used the copy user files from `utilities` method in Toad and it worked like a charm.

Open the Toad for Oracle version you want to export the user settings from and go to the menu and click on `Utilities` then `Copy User Settings…`.

A Copy User Settings dialog box is displayed, you select the second radio button then `Export` and type in or Browse for the local or network path you want to save the generated zip file too.

Then open up the updated Toad for Oracle version and import the same zip file that was generated.

This method is especially useful when you get a new computer and need to install Toad for Oracle again. With this method everything is populated; Passwords, settings, Connection information etc.

Answer (score 2):

As the [answer from user8133620](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44444996/2657515) and the [answer from Saif](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50956581/2657515) have mentioned:

> "Utilities" > "Copy User Settings..."
>   Select "Copy user file from a previous installation"
>   Click "Browse..."

***Tricky part!*** You must browse to your user data area. If you browse to the wrong place, Toad will warn you that the directory you picked doesn't contain a `User Files` directory. And if you browse to the Toad installation directory in `Program Files (x86)`, you will find a `User File` directory; Toad will accept this as valid, but will not actually import your settings.

***This is the one you want:***

> C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Quest Software\Toad for Oracle\11.0

<sub>*You'll have to replace part of the path with your own version number (I was upgrading from version `11.0`).

If you have trouble finding that location, try searching for either of the following files on your hard drive:*</sub>

```
CONNECTIONS.INI
CONNECTIONPWDS.INI
```

***Another tricky part!*** As mentioned in the [answer from Sagar Gangula](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50858466/2657515), you need to have the "Save passwords" box checked. If you do not have this box checked, connections and user names will be imported, but passwords will not be. If you realize your mistake, and check the box and try to import again, existing connections will NOT be updated/overwritten. You must:

- Remove all connections
  *(select all rows using <kbd>Ctrl + click</kbd> with the mouse or by using <kbd>CTRL + A</kbd>, then tap <kbd>Delete</kbd>)*
- Make sure the "Save passwords" box is checked
- Import all connections again

---

Using the "Copy User Settings..." feature *(Toad 12.1.X and above)* will let you do the following in a single step:

- Import/Export all all your preferences *(from the `User Files` directory or a zip archive)*
- Import/Export all your existing connections *(including username & passwords)*
- Transfer all of this from one computer to another ***(including username & passwords!)***

Tested and confirmed in Toad 13.0.0.80

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Talkingbyte.com service as mentioned above does work, but it's not free (~$10). I tested it with a demo server and it worked. It gave me enough of a [free] hint to confirm that it did accurately decrypt the Toad config-file.

Now, I'm not sure I would trust it with my production database passwords, but at least it's an option that works and a last resort should you desperately need it!

Answer (score 0):

Copy CONNECTIONPWDS.INI over you newly installed Toad.  Make sure Toad is closed otherwise it will resort back to no connections.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a dblink for this connection and if you have saved this passw you can see this when you click the option show script.

Answer (score 0):

The DB Link solution mentioned above works but I have some 30+ credentials. For me the following worked:
Export the connections (assuming passwords are saved) and before importing, I updated the value for 'SavePassword' to true and it worked for me.

```
<SavePassword>True</SavePassword>
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to copy the file. I did the same thing to my new system and restart toad, all saved connection from my previous system got loaded.

Comment: I gave up on this a loooong time ago...But if you were able to do it successfully, you must either be using an older or a newer version of Toad - the version I was on, it was impossible to do this, because the file was encrypted with a key unique to the machine (appears to be the network MAC address), so a simple copy/paste wouldn't have worked.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tried this recently but I have certainly successfully transferred the encrypted passwords file from one installation to another (on configuring a new work PC) so if it doesn't work on current versions of TOAD they must have spotted and dealt with that loophole... a pity, because it was so convenient!

There was no option to extract the passwords back then and doesn't seem to be one now.

Answer (score -1):

Can't you just create a query that returns data of the current connection you are trying to get the password for and then export that to Excel. Once the query is in Excel then look at the connection string. Should be able to see the sever, user name and password.